# Spring data mongodb repository findAll field exclusion

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, repository, spring-data-mongodb

I have a strange issue for the spring data mongodb repositories.. I want to exclude a field from my `findAll` request. How can I achieve this ?

This works perfectly:

```
@Query(fields = "{'objectContentAsJson':0}")
Page<ObjectHistory> findByObjectIdAndServiceIgnoreCase( String objectId, String service, Pageable pageable );
```

But no chance for `findAll`:

```
@Query(fields = "{'objectContentAsJson':0}")
Page<ObjectHistory> findAll( Pageable pageable );
```

This throws:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findAll found for type ObjectHistory!    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding an empty filter criteria will do the trick for you:

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'objectContentAsJson':0}")
Page<ObjectHistory> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Apparently, when you do not specify the `value` parameter to filter results, Spring Data tries to derive a query from the method name and somehow, does not recognize the special meaning of `findAll`.

Comment: But I dont get it, it works as mine at the other function

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway !

Comment: In the other case, the query is derivable from the method name.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not providing a **value** field to your @Query annotation, Spring will try to convert the method name *findAll* to a query which is not respecting the Query Creation Specification from Spring.
Please look a the Specs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

This should work for you :

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'objectContentAsJson':0}")
Page<ObjectHistory> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: That's a valid idea but It's `MongoDB` not `JPA`, so you can't use `JPQL`.

Comment: Actually you can, Spring will convert to the underlying Data store. Please See [this example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming) from the Spring Data Mongo Official Documentation.

Comment: First part of this doc meant to be general but used `JPA` specific examples for the demonstration sake. Everything after http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference is for mongo

Comment: If you add a `JPQL` as value, you will get a `JSONParseException`

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Query.html#value--

Comment: @AliDehghani It seems you're right, I'll edit my post !! Thank you for the clarification :)